# Does "cc", "vv", "^^" have a special meaning in code?

Tags: java

Occasionally in code at GitHub I see tags "cc", "vv" and "^^".  Do these have any special meaning?

Example:

```
// cc MaxTemperatureMapper Mapper for maximum temperature example
// vv MaxTemperatureMapper
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MaxTemperatureMapper
  extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

{snip}

}
// ^^ MaxTemperatureMapper
```

From https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch02/src/main/java/MaxTemperatureMapper.java

Comment: The `vv` and `^^` appear to be arrows that enclose the segment specified by `cc`.  I have never seen this style before, though I can certainly imagine some custom scripts using this to identify locations of files and methods (for things similar to [ctags](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/))

Comment: What the.. Why the.. that makes no sense...

Comment: they're probably tags for some code generator or documentation tool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've not seen this before.  It is certainly not part of the Java standards.

I suspect it is something to do with the electronic version of the book that those example files belong to; i.e. some publisher-specific markup for creating an index for the example code.

Ignore it :-)

Comment: It is also common for source code documentation software to have markers in the comments, see e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/XML_Documentation_for_Delphi_Code

Comment: @JanDoggen - That is true.  However, the standard for Java is "javadoc" comments, and these are comments are definitely not that.